# LEFT JOIN in SQL but exclude joining where table1.column1 = 'specific_value'

Tags: sql, left-join, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I'm trying to join 2 data sets that are almost 1:1. `table1` is segmented on `segment1` so that the metrics are split among the possible values of that segment, EX below.

```
| attribute1 | attribute2 | segment1 | metric1           | metric2           |
|------------|------------|----------|-------------------|-------------------|
| bob        | 3          | home     | 1/3 total metric1 | 1/5 total metric2 |
| bob        | 3          | work     | 2/3 total metric1 | 4/5 total metric2 |
| ray        | 5          | home     | 1/3 total metric1 | 1/5 total metric2 |
| ray        | 5          | work     | 2/3 total metric1 | 4/5 total metric2 |
```

`table2` is not segmented, below:

```
| attribute1 | attribute2 | metric3       | metric4       |
|------------|------------|---------------|---------------|
| bob        | 3          | total metric3 | total metric4 |
| ray        | 5          | total metric3 | total metric4 |
```

A regular `LEFT JOIN` then results in duplicated rows from `table2`, since a `table2` row is joined to each `table1.segment1` possibility. So `metric3` and `metric4` are double-counted. I have no other common constraints to `JOIN` on.

```
| attribute1 | attribute2 | segment1 | metric1           | metric2           | metric3       | metric4       |
|------------|------------|----------|-------------------|-------------------|---------------|---------------|
| bob        | 3          | home     | 1/3 total metric1 | 1/5 total metric2 | total metric3 | total metric4 |
| bob        | 3          | work     | 2/3 total metric1 | 4/5 total metric2 | total metric3 | total metric4 |
| ray        | 5          | home     | 1/3 total metric1 | 1/5 total metric2 | total metric3 | total metric4 |
| ray        | 5          | work     | 2/3 total metric1 | 4/5 total metric2 | total metric3 | total metric4 |
```

I think a workaround is to find a way to skip the join operation on all but 1 possible value of the `table1.segment1` field. The `table2` columns would be `NULL` for the other segments of `table1`, but that's ok for now.

My approach was a `CASE` statement in the `JOIN` clause, like so:

```
select
    table1.attribute1,
    table1.attribute2,
    table1.segment1,
    table1.metric1,
    table1.metric2,
    table2.metric3,
    table2.metric4
from table1
left join table2
    on table1.attribute1 = table2.attribute1
    and table1.attribute2 = table2.attribute2
    and CASE
            WHEN table1.segment1 = 'home' then TRUE
            ELSE FALSE
        END
```

This is valid SQL on Redshift. Can anyone verify if this would work, if there is a better way? I'm QAing the data but it's slow and I wanted double confirmation.

Also, this would assume that EVERY possibility of `segment1` exists in `table1` for every record, right? Otherwise I could be filtering out `table2` rows?

Expected (but maybe not the best) results from this:

```
| attribute1 | attribute2 | segment1 | metric1           | metric2           | metric3       | metric4       |
|------------|------------|----------|-------------------|-------------------|---------------|---------------|
| bob        | 3          | home     | 1/3 total metric1 | 1/5 total metric2 | total metric3 | total metric4 |
| bob        | 3          | work     | 2/3 total metric1 | 4/5 total metric2 | NULL          | NULL          |
| ray        | 5          | home     | 1/3 total metric1 | 1/5 total metric2 | total metric3 | total metric4 |
| ray        | 5          | work     | 2/3 total metric1 | 4/5 total metric2 | NULL          | NULL          |
```

Comment: You don't clearly describe how desired output is a function of input. You just give fragmented partial descriptions of what you want or got. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. PS Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. PS [mre]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by attribute1, attribute2 order by attribute1) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 left join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by attribute1, attribute2 order by attribute1) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t2.attribute1 = t1.attribute1 and
        t2.attribute2 = t1.attribute2 and
        t2.seqnum = t1.seqnum
```